# Mocking away captcha field when testing zend Form

Tags: php, zend-framework, mocking, phpunit, zend-form

I want to test my form which I have created with Zend_Form. Now the problem is that I have a captcha field within my form. And I was told by one of the Zend Framework Guru's that I should mock  away the validation of the captcha field a mock object.

I have read this http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.0/en/mock-objects.html on the PHPUnit manual. But I really don't understand how I can mock away a validator.

Does anyone have experience with this? Can anyone help me out?

Thanks

---

More information:

I want my test not to break because it can't test the captcha field. So I need to find out some way the post will not be stopped because of the captcha field.

```
public function testCanSubmitContactForm(){
   $mock = $this->getMock('Zend_Form_Element_Captcha', array(), '', false);
   $mock->expects($this->once()->method("isValid")->will($this->resturnValue(true)));

   $this->request->setMethod('post')
                 ->setPost(array(
                     'email'    => 'someemail@adres.com',
                     'comment'  => 'Testing the bladiebla contact form'
                     'captcha'  =>  ''//no idea  
                 ));
   $this->dispach('/contact');


}
```

Here is how my Zend_Form generated form looks like:

```
    <form id="contact-form" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="post" action="/index/contact"><dl class="zend_form">

<dt id="email-label"><label for="email" class="required">Uw E-mailadres</label></dt>

<dd id="email-element">
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" /></dd>

<dt id="comment-label"><label for="comment" class="required">Stel hieronder uw vraag of geef je commentaar op</label></dt>

<dd id="comment-element">

<textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="71" rows="24"></textarea></dd>

<dt id="captcha-input-label"><label for="captcha-input" class="required">SPAM Beveiliging</label></dt>

<dd id="captcha-element">

<pre> _    _    __   __    ______    ______    ______     ___    
| \  / ||  \ \\/ //  /_   _//  /_   _//  /_____//   / _ \\  
|  \/  ||   \ ` //   `-| |,-    -| ||-   `____ `   | / \ || 
| .  . ||    | ||      | ||     _| ||_   /___//    | \_/ || 
|_|\/|_||    |_||      |_||    /_____//  `__ `      \___//  
`-`  `-`     `-`'      `-`'    `-----`   /_//       `---`   
                                         `-`                
</pre> 


<input type="hidden" name="captcha[id]" value="a4957b2dbfea79d8bd654428f6eb0a2c" id="captcha-id" />

<input type="text" name="captcha[input]" id="captcha-input" value="" />

<p class="description">Voer de 6 letters in die hierboven getoond worden. Deze vraag wordt gebruikt om te testen of u een menselijke bezoeker bent teneinde spam-inzendingen te vermijden.</p></dd>

<dt id="submit-label">&#160;</dt><dd id="submit-element">

<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Nu Versturen" /></dd></dl></form>
```

Comment: Please link to: http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/index.html 3.0 is pretty old and outdated :) (I assume you use 3.5 ?) --- I'm not to firm with Zend Framework so to provide a meaningfull answer i'd need to see some code. But i'm sure someone else can answer this anyways :)

Comment: You could add an exception in your code generating you form to to generate the captcha based on your application environment (not the best way for 100% code coverage, but i could keep you running for now)

Comment: @Jeff. This is how I deal with testing forms with captcha. The reason is that usually processing and validating captcha is ZFs job, meaning that you, as a developer, do not create any custom logic or code for it.

Comment: @jeff can you provide a detailed example?

Comment: Based on the default setting in zend in the index.php file in the public folder the constant 'APPLICATION_ENV' is defined and if no value is received through the getenv (you can send this info through the .htaccess with env_module enabled in apache) the value is automatically set to production. In your form generating code you could do a check on that constant like if(APPLICATION_ENV == 'production'){ // create captcha element }

Comment: assuming that for running tests you set you application_env to testing, this should work

Comment: It comes that way out of the box, and I worked with it quite a bit, ie: if I'm in a development environment, when my application is sending emails, i send them to my own mailbox and I use it to display more informations like each query that runs with related stats.

Answer (score 3):

I'll just fire away, let me know if this is what you want:

From: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardElements.html

```
// Concrete instance:
$element->setCaptcha(new Zend_Captcha_Figlet());
```

You can't unit test this since you can't do dependency injection (as with many parts of zend framework as you sure have figured out) so you need some way to inject that into your form builder.

```
public function setCaptcha(Zend_Captcha $cap) { // override the default cap }
```

or if your application allows for it pass it in the constructor (would be better anyways but can be hard with zf)

Then you have your standard mock:

```
$mock = $this->getMock("Zend_Form_Element_Captcha", array(), array(), '', false /*don't call original constructor'*/);
$mock->expects($this->once())->method("isValid")->will($this->returnValue(true)); // Not sure about the method name ;)
```

And add that in instead of the default captcha element.

Not sure what part of the problem you where having trouble with so i went over everything a little

Comment: This gives errors in my tests: 
1) IndexControllerTest::testCanSubmitContactForm
Argument 3 passed to PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase::getMock() must be an array, str
ing given, called in K:\stage5\tests\application\controllers\IndexControllerTest
.php on line 92 and defined

Comment: Edited the answers to account for that

Answer (score 0):

You just have to separate the captcha element from the form, e.g. create:

```
public function addCaptcha()
{
   $this->addElement()...
}

protected $_enableCaptcha = true;

public function disableCaptcha()
{
   $this->_enableCaptcha = false;
}

public function init()
{
   //    ...
   if ($this->_enableCaptcha) {
      $this->addCaptcha();
   }

}
```

Then in your test just disable the CAPTCHA.

Maybe Zend Form or Captcha Element already has some method to do so.

You may also create base form without captcha and test it and next subclass the form and add captcha element.

Answer (score -1):

For testing you can use this condition in your form:

```
if (!\Zend_Session::$_unitTestEnabled) {
     $this->addElement($captcha);
}
```